# Django Get Primary + Foreign Attributes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have two models: `Site` and `Metric`.

I want to display the `Metric` values alongside each `Site`.

My `views.py` is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Site, Metric
def site_graph(request):
    sites = Site.objects.order_by('name')
    metrics = [s.metric_set.all() for s in sites]
    return render(request, 'da/site_graph.html', {'sites': sites, 'metrics': metrics})
```

And my template content looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for metric in  metrics %}
        [
        {% for query in metric %}
            {{ query.domain_authority }}
            {{ query.date_queried }}
        {% endfor %}
        ]
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I am not sure how I would go about getting the data I need in Django.

This data is going to be eventually passed onto `d3.js` for visualization which is why I need the data from the matching the primary key for each `Site` to be together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of dictionaries:

```
def site_graph(request):
    metrics=[]
    sites = Site.objects.order_by('name')
    for site in sites:
        metrics_site={}
        metrics_site["site"] = site
        metrics_site["metrics"] = site.metric_set.all()
        metrics.append(metrics_site)
    return render(request, 'da/site_graph.html', {'metrics': metrics})
```

And then in the template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for metric in  metrics %}
        {{ metric.site.name }}
        {% for query in metric.metrics %}
            {{ query.domain_authority }}
            {{ query.date_queried }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

metric.site.name is just an example if your model "site" contains a field "name" that you want to show.